# How to set up two-factor authentication with OTP on FreeBSD?

Tags: security, ssh, freebsd, password, pam

I have a FreeBSD server that I like to be able to get to from anywhere. Normally I use SSH publickey to log in, or if I don't have my SSH private key available then I might use regular password over SSH. However, when logging in from an untrusted machine there's always the risk of a keylogger capturing my login password as I type it.

FreeBSD already has [support for OPIE](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/one-time-passwords.html) which is a one-time password scheme. This works great, but the one-time password is the *only* authentication needed. If I print out a list of one-time passwords to use later, then if I lose that list then that's all somebody needs.

I'd like to set up the authentication so that I need a one-time password *plus* something I know (a password, except not my usual login password). I have a feeling the answer has something to do with [PAM](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pam/) (and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`) but I'm not certain on the details.

How can I set up authentication where two methods are required?

Comment: If you lost the list of OTPs, wouldn't you know this and change your opie password?

Comment: @Chris S: that assumes you can log in to the server from wherever you are without having your OTP list.

Comment: Considering OPIE hasn't been updated in almost 16 years, I'm sure it was an oversight at the time; I don't know of a way to do what you're asking, but it definitely sounds like a really good idea that should be implemented. My smart@ss answer to being able to login from almost everywhere: consider getting a smart phone with PocketPutty or a similar app.

Answer (score 1):

google authenticator maybe? I have my OpenSolaris box asking first for normal login password, then the TOTP verification code. Something like this: http://www.marzocchi.net/Olafsen/Software/Two-FactorAuthentication

Comment: Again, missing the requirement that the normal login password *not* be used as the password element.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to stack the normal ’ssh_auth’ module with the ‘pam_opie‘ module using the ‘required‘ control flag.

Comment: That would expose his actual password; the question specifically said "except not my usual login password"

Comment: Ah, I missed that! Then he needs a pam module which uses a static second password with ssh-kbdint. Unfortunately I don't know of anyone who has written such a module, but it isn't very hard as you can use ssh_auth and modify it to use another password file.